# Why aren't these elements overlapping?

Tags: css, overlap

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="promo">
    <p class="preview"><a href="#"><img src="preview.png"></a></p>
    <p class="caption"><a href="/">Project caption</a></p>
</div>

.promo .preview img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.promo .caption {
    background: white;
    padding: 0.50em;
    margin-top: -2.00em;
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image: Overlapping result]

Why does the caption element not overlap the image? It does overlap the `.preview` div without an image in it. It also does not overlap when the image has `display: inline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force the caption to go up with `position: relative; z-index: 2;`.

The behaviour of overlap is unpredictable with staticly positioned elements. The `z-index` property lets you state clearly if you want it above or below another element. The `position` property is mandatory for this to work.

Comment: This works, thank you! Would you mind explaining why it works?